# Ideas for architecting REST interfaces (Spring MVC vs JAX-RS implementation)

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a one liner requirement saying our new product should support REST interfaces. I am new to webservices and Spring. So I am trying to narrow down on the must have technologies, so I can research on them. I seem to have too many options:

1. Use Spring MVC's support of RESTful webservices.
2. Use a JAX-RS implementation like Jersey and integrate with Spring.
3. Use a REST oriented framework like Apache Wink. We have a JSP UI as the main client, though some customers would use the REST interface we expose. So, may be we need some framework that is more than a pure REST oriented one?
4. Are there any client side implementation needed to work with REST interfaces? I see a lot of reference to AJAX, java script. So what are the client implications for JSP pages?

Any input on the highlevel architectural blocks you have used to implement restful webservices would provide me points to start. My head is spinning with all the webservices and Spring related stuff I am reading :)

Comment: You're going to want some more detailed requirements.

Comment: I could only get the background info that drove this requirement. Some customers (resellers basically) want to integrate our product functionality to their UI. To them, 'need webservices' seems to say it all. So, what kind of questions would you ask to help choose the right direction?

Comment: Security, what types of filtering, whether the REST is pure viewing, or can you update products. Stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks! I will post with additional requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across my own question that I had posted 8 years ago. To bring closure, here is what we ended up doing: Retired JSP UI, adopted AngularJS frontend and Jersey based APIs on the backend. Since then we have moved to Angular + Spring REST while Jersey continues with legacy code.